# How to return arithmetic operator from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of the form `<op>(</op><num>1553446</num><op>+</op><num>1553448</num><op>)</op>` . The operator may be `+`,`-`,`*` or `/`. I need to retrieve the operator only from such a string in the most efficient way possible (using C# code).

The data is not a form of XML(though it may look like). I have the string as a whole.

Other examples of the string

`<op>(</op><num>1545646</num><op>*</op><num>1521248</num><op>)</op>`

`<op>(</op><num>1345346</num><op>/</op><num>15212</num><op>)</op>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into Regular Expressions...

Comment: If this is XML, aren't you really just trying to extract the contents of any `op` element? I would also encourage you to focus on *correct* and *simple* code first - then define performance requirements and see if you can meet them with the simple code. Trying to go straight for the most efficient code possible is almost never a good idea.

Comment: This data does not come from XML

Comment: So using `RegularExpressions` will be a good option...but don't know how...So need help!!

Comment: But will it always be valid XML if you add a root element open/close to the start/end? In particular, your example shows `(` and `)` as contents of `<op>` elements... will there ever be a `<` operator, and how would that be represented?

Comment: I know '(' and ')' are used with `<op>` tags in the string...but there will never be a `>` or `<` operator

Comment: So are you trying to extract those `(` and `)` as well? (You don't mention them in the list.) Might there be more operators in the string, or will there only ever be one? More examples might help.

Comment: No `(` and `)` are not to be extracted. I have included other examples of the string as well.

Comment: I edited my answer with what you asked for, but it's full of premises... hope this helps you, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `Regex` to extract `+` `-` `/` `*` and `numbers`. After getting the elements, it can be used as required.

```
        string a = "<op>(</op><num>1553446</num><op>+</op>
                   <num>1553448</num><op>)</op>";

        Regex reg = new Regex(@"<op>[\+\-\*\/]?</op>");
        MatchCollection matches = reg.Matches(a);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value); //output <op>+</op>

        reg = new Regex(@"<num>\d*</num>");
        matches = reg.Matches(a);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value); 
        //output <num>1553446</num> <num>1553448</num>

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to get  element value:

Using regular expressions.
Using [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
     XDocument xmlObj = XDocument.Load(str);
     var query = from c in xmlObj.Elements("op")
                 select c.Value;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use either of those - I'd just load the document into `XDocument` and go straight from there. Two lines of code...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, you're right.

Comment: Note that the string isn't quite valid XML at the moment - you'd need something like `"<root>" + str + "</root>"` - at which point you either need to load it as `XElement` rather than `XDocument`, or use `xmlobj.Root.Elements("op")`

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza your solution will give me operators `(` and `)` as well which I do not need. Moreover as @JonSkeet said the string is not exactly in a valid XML form.

Answer (score 0):

What is *efficient* for you?

- fast execution time but cumbersome code;
- quick to implement and easy to read?

Depending on this you can use indices, `String::IndexOf()` or `XDocument`. They are on opposite poles but all have advantages and disadvantages.

EDIT:

Ok, I see you've commented quite a bit and I came up with a really *UGLY* solution that I would never use. But as much as I can tell, this is what you want.

Don't downvote, this is intentionally ugly code :)

Say, your string to parse is `str`. The following code will tell you which of the 4 operands is in the string, but *absolutely* no other test is made. This code may be the source of much trouble, but... here you go:

```
class ...
{
    private static readonly char[] OPERATORS = new char[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

    public char GetOperator(string str) // may be static
    {
        int i;

        i = str.Replace("</", "").IndexOfAny(OPERATORS);

        return i == -1 ? '_' : OPERATORS[i];
    }
}
```

You'll get an `'_'` underscore character if no operand has been recognized.
If there is more than one operator you'll get only the first one.

Comment: fast execution time but cumbersome code

Comment: @user1603970: Have you defined your performance requirements yet? If you haven't got *any* code working yet, how do you know that you need the fastest possible code, when *simple* code may well perform well enough for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not have any code with me...if simple code works fine then I am good to go. It is not necessary that the code has to be cumbersome.